# Split and Join images in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, histogram

I am trying to split an image using image slicer in python and then apply histogram equalization on each of them and combine them back. I am able to split the images into smaller blocks and I can see them being updated but after stitching them together I end up with the same image as the original one. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong. The file name is watch.png

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imsave
# import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc
import scipy

import sys
import argparse
import image_slicer
from image_slicer import join


img = 'watch.png'
num_tiles = 64
tiles = image_slicer.slice(img, num_tiles)



file = "watch"
k = 0
filelist =[]
for i in range(1,9):
    for j in range(1,9):
        filelist.insert(k, file+"_"+str(i).zfill(2)+"_"+str(j).zfill(2)+".png")
        k=k+1

for i in range(0,num_tiles):
    img = scipy.misc.imread(filelist[i])
    hist,bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(),256,[0,256])
    cdf = hist.cumsum()
    cdf_normalized = cdf *hist.max()/ cdf.max()  
    plt.plot(cdf_normalized, color = 'g')
    plt.hist(img.flatten(),256,[0,256], color = 'g')
    plt.xlim([0,256])
    plt.legend(('cdf','histogram'), loc = 'upper left')
    cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)
    cdf_o = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*255/(cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())
    cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_o,0).astype('uint8')
    img3 = cdf[img]
    cv2.imwrite(filelist[i],img3)


image = join(tiles)
image.save('watch-join.png')
```

Comment: Your example seems to be incomplete as you never store your tiles in the files inserted in the `filelist`. However, guessing from the code I do think you do that, since you seem to be able to read the different images. But my guess is that you forget to update the `tiles`so at the very end, you just `join` the original, unmodified (thus, not updated) tiles, which of course gives you the original image again.

Comment: @JohanL I am writing the modified image block back to the same file name so I think it should not make a difference. I tried printing tiles and it gave me the list of file names that it refers to and they point to the correct file names. Is there any other way you would suggest updating tiles before I stitch the images back

Comment: @user2808264- Is any difference between applying histogram equalization on complete image and other side applying on each part of image like your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking into the `image_slicer` code, I can see the confusion. The main problem is that each `Tile` object, contains both the image data and metadata, such as filename and position in final image. However, the image data is not updated when the files pointed to are updated.

Thus, when updating the files pointed to by the metadata also the image object of the tile needs to be updated. I imagine the simplest way to do this, is to reopen the image in the tile whenever the file on disk is changed. This is likely to do the trick:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imsave
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc
import scipy
import image_slicer
from image_slicer import join
from PIL import Image

img = 'watch.png'
num_tiles = 64
tiles = image_slicer.slice(img, num_tiles)

for tile in tiles:
    img = scipy.misc.imread(tile.filename)
    hist,bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(),256,[0,256])
    cdf = hist.cumsum()
    cdf_normalized = cdf *hist.max()/ cdf.max()  
    plt.plot(cdf_normalized, color = 'g')
    plt.hist(img.flatten(),256,[0,256], color = 'g')
    plt.xlim([0,256])
    plt.legend(('cdf','histogram'), loc = 'upper left')
    cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)
    cdf_o = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*255/(cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())
    cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_o,0).astype('uint8')
    img3 = cdf[img]
    cv2.imwrite(tile.filename,img3)
    tile.image = Image.open(tile.filename)

image = join(tiles)
image.save('watch-join.png')
```

Thus, the main change is to add `tile.image = Image.open(tile.filename)` at the end of the loop. Note also that I have updated your code slightly, by removing the first loop that generates the filenames, and instead the second loop is over the tiles directly, as they contain the needed information all ready.

Comment: Unfortunately this throws an error saying that 
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: My bad. Image.open is a class method and not an object metod. Thus it needs to be called with `Image.open()`. This also requires `Image`to be imported. I have updated the code.

Comment: @JohanL- Is any difference between applying histogram equalization on complete image and other side applying on each part of image like your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is the source code for `image_slicer.join()`:

```
def join(tiles):
    """
    @param ``tiles`` - Tuple of ``Image`` instances.
    @return ``Image`` instance.
    """
    im = Image.new('RGB', get_combined_size(tiles), None)
    columns, rows = calc_columns_rows(len(tiles))
    for tile in tiles:
        im.paste(tile.image, tile.coords)
    return im
```

As you can see, it uses the `Tile` objects stored in the program (in your case, inside the list `tiles`), which haven't changed. You need to either change the objects in memory instead of loading from the file and rewriting, or load the files into `tiles` as well.

The easy way in my opinion is to modify your for loop (I hope I got the syntax right):

```
for i in range(0, num_tiles):
    img = tiles[i].image
    hist, bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(), 256, [0, 256])
    cdf = hist.cumsum()
    cdf_normalized = cdf * hist.max() / cdf.max()  
    plt.plot(cdf_normalized, color = 'g')
    plt.hist(img.flatten(), 256, [0, 256], color='g')
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
    plt.legend(('cdf', 'histogram'), loc='upper left')
    cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf, 0)
    cdf_o = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min()) * 255 / (cdf_m.max() - cdf_m.min())
    cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_o, 0).astype('uint8')
    img3 = cdf[img]
    tiles[i].image = img3
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do this because using the above method it is unable to apply the flatten function 
I end up with this error 
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Comment: If you split the image into slice, how to you merge back?