# Slicing the image, do some processing and combine the slices in to a single image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Lets say I have an image in a folder and I have splitted the image in to 9 tiles and have found out the contours in each tile and fitted a minimal rectangle for every contour.

The below is for taking an image and slicing it and saving the tiles to a directory

```
    def image_slice(img):
        tiles = image_slicer.slice(img, 8, save=False) #get_columns_rows
        image_slicer.save_tiles(tiles, directory=path_to_directory
        prefix='slice') #Slicing the image and saving it to a directory
```

Now I want to combine all the tiles form the folder in to a single image something like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZidyP.jpg)

I know about the image_slicer.join() but I need a definition that can merge the tiles

Now further ahead its just for one image in the folder I want to scale it for multiple images in the folder

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're looking for [image stitching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html).

Comment: These would typically be called "tiles". "Slices" are 2D subsets of 3D images. Makes your question a bit confusing to me. :)

Comment: I apologize for creating confusion. I meant tiles not slides. I have edited the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split and join images in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565275/split-and-join-images-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, when you create the original slicer, make a copy of it, using deepcopy. Example, stiles = deepcopy(main_tiles)

now as you process images and modify them, you can replace them with tiles of stiles. Example:  stiles[i].image = Image.fromarray(cutout)

Then finally call join(stiles). Voila, you got the combined pre-processed images.

Comment: I applied image_slicer to cut and join the image and it works for me but I am getting the horizontal and vertical lines on the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZidyP.jpg
How can I remove those lines?