# Joining edited images in python using numpy image slicer

Tags: image, numpy, python-3.6

I am learning image manipulation as a beginner in python. My goal is to section my image into an nxn grid where each square is the average color (greyscale image) of the original, respectively. I succeeded in splitting the image, changing its pixel data and saving the new images. My problem is now stitching the image back together. I know the join function is pointing back to the original image, I had hoped that by saving over the tiles I could work around this.

This is my first time posting to stackoverflow (and I am super, super new to python), so apologies if I am not clear or if the formatting is wrong.

```
# Import packages 
import numpy as np
from numpy import matlib
import PIL
import image_slicer
import math
import glob
from image_slicer import join
from PIL import Image

### Use PIL to import image
##img = Image.open("einstein.jpg")

# Display original image
# img.show()


##new_img = img.resize((256,256))
##new_img.save('einstein-256x256','png')
### new_img.show()

#Slice image into four pieces
tiles = image_slicer.slice("einstein.jpg", 16)

# Use glob to open every .png file with for loop
for filename in glob.glob("*.png"):
    img=Image.open(filename)

    pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map
    pixelMap = img.load() #create the pixel map

    #convert to array
    arr = np.asarray(img)

    #find mean 
    pixelMean = arr.mean(0).mean(0)[0]

    # Convert mean to integer 
    IntMean = math.floor(pixelMean)
    print(IntMean)


    ##pixel = pixelMap[0,0] #get the first pixel's value
    ##print(pixel)

    # Loop for going through every pixel in image and converting it
    for i in range(img.size[0]):    # for every col:
        for j in range(img.size[1]):    # For every row

            pixels[i,j] = (IntMean,IntMean,IntMean) # set the colour             accordingly

    # Save new monotone images
    img.save(filename)

# Join new images into one 
image = join(tiles)
# Save new image
image.save("einsteinJoined.jpg")

image.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be missing the error you get with your current code.

However, if I read it correctly, you will get back your original image, as was the problem in [Split and Join images in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565275/split-and-join-images-in-python). Similar to the answer accepted there, the solution is to change the image in each tile by ending your loop with:

```
tile.image = Image.open(filename)
```

Where tile is the tile corresponding to the file, you should loop over the tiles from the image_slicer.slice-function to do so. This is also given in answer to the question linked to.