# Python: How to split image into blocks. Then join into original image

Tags: python, image, numpy-ndarray

I need to split a 768 x 1024 image into 16 x 16 blocks. And then I need to join them into the original image. I tried a lot of ways, but cannot get original image.

I used this method to split test image (size = 768 x 1024) into 16 x 16 blocks, and save into block list. But how to join them into original image?

```
block = []
for x in range(0, test.shape[0],16):
    for y in range(0, test.shape[1],16):
        block.append(test[x:x+16, y:y+16])
```

Comment: What do you mean by the original image?

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565275/split-and-join-images-in-python ?

Comment: You can use Numpy's vstack and hstack functions. First run a hstack for every 48 blocks and then run the vstack on the resulting hstack images.

Comment: Thank you, let me try these methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "join to the original original"? It's not clear what you want your final output to be. Rather than an abstract/theoretical 768 x 1024 image, mock up a 16x16 and show the output you want if you split it into 4x4 blocks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
test = test.reshape((-1,16,16,3)) #breaking image into 3072 16x16 blocks
test = test.reshape((1024,768,3)) #rejoining 3072 blocks into 1 image
```